# Android: ContentProvider for each table / handling one-to-many relationships

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, one-to-many

When using a content provider for SQLite database access

1. Is it better practice to have a content provider for each table or to use one for all tables?
2. How to handle one-to-many relationships when creating new records?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail on what you mean with "How to handle one to man relationships" are you talking about SQL Database design, CREATE Statements or are you wondering how to do this on the Content Provider side.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**A ContentProvider is not a database**

A ContentProvider is a way to publicly (or semi-publicly) access data as content. This may be done in a number of ways, via file access, SQLite or even web access. A ContentProvider in and of itself is not a database, but you can program a database for it. You may also have multiple ContentProviders accessing the same database, but distributing different levels of access, or the same content in different ways according to the requestor.

What you are really asking is not a ContentProvider question, but a database question "How to handle relationships in an SQLite database" because the ContentProvider doesn't use any database code unless you tell it to via an `SQLiteOpenHelper` and other similar classes. So, you simply have to program your database access correctly and your SQLite database will work as desired.

**A database is a database**

In the old days, databases were simply flat files where each table was often its own entity to allow for growth. Now, with DBMS, there is very little reason to ever do that. SQLite is just like any other database platform in this regard and can house as many tables as you have space to hold them.

**SQLite**

There are certain features that SQLite handles well, some that it handles - but not well, and some that it does not handle at all. Relationships are one of those things that were left out of some versions of Android's SQLite, because it shipped without foreign key support. This was a highly requested feature and it was added in SQLite 3.6.22 which didn't ship until Android 2.2. There are still many reported bugs with it, however, in its earliest incarnations.

**Android pre 2.2**

Thankfully being SQL compliant and a simple DBMS (not RDBMS at this time), there are some easy ways to work around this, after all, a foreign key is just a field in another table.

1. You can enforce database `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements by creating `CONSTRAINT`s when you use your `CREATE TABLE` statement.
2. You can query the other table for the appropriate `_id` to get your foreign key.
3. You can query your source table with any appropriate `SELECT` statement using an `INNER JOIN`, thus enforcing a pseudo-relationship.

Since Android's version of SQLite does not enforce relationships directly, if you wanted to `CASCADE ON DELETE` you would have to do it manually. But this can be done via another simple SQL statement. I have essentially written my own library to enforce these kinds of relationships, as it all must be done manually. I must say, however, the efficiency of SQLite and SQL as a whole makes this very quick and easy.

In essence, the process for any enforced relationship goes as follows:

- In a query that requires a foreign key, use a `JOIN`.
- In an `INSERT` use a `CONSTRAINT` on the foreign key field of `NOT NULL`
- In an `UPDATE` on the primary key field that is a foreign key in another `TABLE`, run a second `UPDATE` on the related `TABLE` that has the foreign key. (CASCADE UPDATE)
- For a `DELETE` with the same parameters, do another `DELETE` with the where being `foreign_key = _id` (make sure you get the `_id` before you `DELETE` the row, first).

**Android 2.2+**

Foreign keys is supported, but is off by default. First you have to turn them on:

```
db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
```

Next you have to create the relationship `TRIGGER`. This is done when you create the `TABLE`, rather than a separate `TRIGGER` statement. See below:

```
// Added at the end of CREATE TABLE statement in the MANY table
FOREIGN KEY(foreign_key_name) REFERENCES one_table_name(primary_key_name)
```

For further information on SQLite and its capabilities, check out [SQLite official site](http://www.sqlite.org/). This is important as you don't have all of the `JOIN`s that you do in other RDBMS. For specific information on the SQLite classes in Android, read [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html).

Comment: What a cracking answer, thankyou. I'm familiar with many databases (MySQL, MSSQL, Postgres, Ingres, SQLite to name a few and many languages) but this is my first android app and I've forgotten more about JAVA than I really care to admit, What I'm really struggling with is android specific syntax and I should have made that clearer in my question but you have highlighted some serious gaps in my knowledge especially switching on fk's. I'll accept your answer as I now have enough info to phrase more specific questions and I'm sure that others will find this extremely usefull. Thanks again

Answer (score 5):

As for first question: you don't need to create content provider for every table. You can use in with multiple tables, but the complexity of provider increased with each table.

Comment: Thank you, I don't want to mark your question as answered as I don't have answers to all my questions but your info is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

A Content Provider is roughly equivalent to the concept of a database. You'd have multiple tables in a database, so having multiple tables in your content provider makes perfect sense.

One to many relationships can be handled just like in any other database. Use references and foreign keys like you would with any other database. You can use things like CASCADE ON DELETE to make sure records are deleted when the records they reference in other tables are also deleted.